# Get Tooltip content from a point from a line/scatter plot in highcharts from javascript

Tags: javascript, highcharts, tooltip, mouseevent

Can anyone tell me how to get all the values of a line series in a HighChart line plot(http://www.highcharts.com/demo/) through JavaScript? 
Also, how to get tooltip value of a point of a scatter plot through JavaScript?
I have tried triggering 'mouseover' using the following code on a basic line chart (above link) to get tooltip.

```
function simulateMouseOver() {
  var event = new MouseEvent('mouseover', {
    'view': window,
    'bubbles': true,
    'cancelable': true
  });
  var cb = document.querySelector("g.highcharts-tracker:nth-of-type(2)>path:nth-of-type(1)")
  var canceled = !cb.dispatchEvent(event);
  if (canceled) {
    // A handler called preventDefault.
  //  alert("canceled");
  } else {
    // None of the handlers called preventDefault.
 //   alert("not canceled");
  }
}
```

(ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events)
However this doesn't show the tooltip. Can someone help on this?

Poornima

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Can anyone tell me how to get all the values of a line series in a HighChart line plot(http://www.highcharts.com/demo/) through JavaScript?" You can get it from global object.

See example: http://jsfiddle.net/yR3EG/

```
$.each(chart.series,function(i,serie){

            $.each(serie.data,function(j,point){
                console.log(point.y);
            });

        });
```

"Also, how to get tooltip value of a point of a scatter plot through JavaScript?"
You need to get values of point in tooltip or somewhere different?

Comment: Thanks Sebastian, Can you tell me how to get reference to "chart". I need to run this code from test so I wont be able to hook into HighChart creation. I need to get the tooltip content of point. Manually when I hover mouse on the point I am able to see the tooltip. However programmatically I am not able to make to tooltip visible (with "mouseover") to read the content (text tspan) of the tooltip. "mouseover" on a bar chart is working fine.

Comment: I could get the chart object using `var chart = Highcharts.charts[0]`. I need to get tooltip content at a point on scatter/line plot. Can you please help me with getting tooltip content?

Comment: Generlaly tooltip is single object, and when you hover on point, then content is added, so getting cotnent from outside action is not possible.

Comment: What you mean, set mouseover on point ? you can use http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.point.events.mouseOver

Comment: I want to simulate(trigger) mouseover event at a point using JavaScript. I am automating some tests and I need to verify the tooltip value at a point in line/scatter plot. To test this I need to simulate mouseover event at that point. I have tried raising "mouseover" using the above JavaScript. However, this is not showing the tooltip.